# The tilting of solar cells and their efficiency

Tags: classical-mechanics, optics, solar-cells

This is a thought experiment I am considering. It concerns putting solar panels on a flat roof. The question is whether one should tilt them. Whilst there are more mundane reasons for tilting them (eg to clean the panels when it rains), I want to leave aside such "secondary" practical matters and focus only on efficiency.

If you Google this you will find all sorts of nonsense. One usually hears things like 'tilting increases the efficiency'. Let me attempt my own analysis before I ask the main question.

Clearly a one dimensional roof is enough to see the physics. If one has $N$ panels of length $L$ placed flat on a roof of length $NL$ and then sun is at an angle $\theta$ relative to the horizontal, and say $W_0$ is the power coming just from the sun's direct rays, one should find the total power is $W_0 NL \sin\theta$ multiplied by the panel's efficiency.

If we now tilt the panels by $\alpha$ towards the sun, and place them at $D=L\sin(\theta+\alpha)/\sin(\theta)$ apart, which is the minimal length such that none is in shadow, one gets power $W = W_0 \lfloor N \sin(\theta)/\sin(\theta + \alpha) \rfloor \cdot L \sin(\theta + \alpha)$, using the floor function, since I can only squeeze a certain number of such panels onto the same sized roof. If we ignore this, the two are the same, as we should expect because the same solid angle is being subtended either way.

The floor function should be rather negligible I assume (do we agree?). Anyway, the above is of course a little simplistic. There is a lot of diffuse light coming from other parts of the sky. Because of this, we can move the tilted panels closer together. However, I have no estimate for the total power, and also one would really need a power distribution over a half sphere to integrate over to get a more realistic result.

By the way, I have assumed that there is no explicit angular dependence in the efficiency solar cells (other than the obvious dependence on the subtended solid angle). Perhaps someone more expert than I am can confirm how true this is?

Now, my main question is can anybody help estimate whether the added energy from diffuse sunlight adds a non-negligible amount of power to the system, so that one really could say that the tilted panels are more efficient?

Also, am I forgetting something crucial which would change things?

Edit: some of the comments raised interesting points before they were censured into 'chat'. To summarise, there may be some 'intrinsic' angular dependence of solar panels on angle of incidence due to more light being reflected when at more extreme angles. Is this important? Can someone estimate or provide a reference?

To summarise the question then, estimate 1) efficiency of solar panels under diffuse light from around the sky, 2) reflectivity angular dependence of solar panels and the corresponding change in efficiency, 3) list more factors I have left out.

As a final note, I am interested in efficiency per roof, not per panel. Of course having tilted panels means fewer panels must be purchased, but the installation cost may also be higher, so it is not a priori clear that tilted panels are even cost efficient - unless the factors discussed above are important.

Many thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137319/discussion-on-question-by-dlw-the-tilting-of-solar-cells-and-their-efficiency).